# mysql in clause bug?

Tags: mysql, in-clause

Server version: 5.6.22 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

execute below query:

```
SELECT EXECUTION_ID_ FROM `ACT_RU_EXECUTION` WHERE BUSINESS_KEY_='ZZJS481';
```

throw this error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'EXECUTION_ID_' in 'field list'

but when this error statement in IN clause, like below:

```
select EXECUTION_ID_ FROM `ACT_RU_TASK` WHERE EXECUTION_ID_ IN (SELECT EXECUTION_ID_ FROM `ACT_RU_EXECUTION` WHERE BUSINESS_KEY_='ZZJS481');
```

no error will raise.
It looks really strange. 
Does this a bug in MySQL?

Comment: Does the `ACT_RU_EXECUTION` table have an `EXECUTION_ID_` field?

Comment: ACT_RU_EXECUTION does not have EXECUTION_ID_ field.

Comment: It is my mistake. It is general operation for mysql and other RDB database systems.